# Two Tables Relationship based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-design

I am stuck in the following situations.

I have two tables `Products` and `Postage`:

`Postage` table

```
+----------------------------------+
| Weight_GM  | Postal Charges ($)  |
+----------------------------------+
|   20       |  1                  |
|   40       |  1.5                |
|   50       |  1.7                |
+----------------------------------+
```

`Products` table

```
+-------------------------------+
| SKU   | Title     | Weight_GM |
+-------------------------------+
| ABC   | Shose     |   17      |
| JKL   | Camera    |   27      |
| XYZ   | IPad      |   48      |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want to create a relationship to take appropriate postal charge from `Postage` table based on the `Weight` defined in both tables.

The desired result would be like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| SKU   | Title     | Weight_GM | Postal Charges    |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ABC   | Shose     |   17      |   1               |
| JKL   | Camera    |   27      |   1.5             |
| XYZ   | IPad      |   48      |   1.7             |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: I have been through many similar questions but there was not solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the rules for rounding?

Comment: rounding? Sorry cant got to your point?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mehboob how would you describe the pricing in words? Eg "Up to 40 grams it's $1.5, etc" . What about 40 grams exactly?

Comment: Look if weight <=20 then Postage = $1, if weight >20 and <=40 then Postage=$1.5 and so on.

Comment: @Mehboob: Can you amend the structure of `Postage` so that it can have a start_weight_range column, as well as the existing maximum weight column?

Comment: You can use a cursor to accomplish this.

Comment: @rontornambe: You could use pencil and paper, too - it would be about as desirable.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I can't amend the structure, because my client doesn't allow me.

Comment: So a package that weighs 20.5 grams is $1.5?  @MarkBannister - `start_weight_range` is derived information, and shouldn't be stored.  It can be calculated on-the-fly fairly trivially, if actually necessary.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: According to relational theory, you're right - derived information should not be stored. In this type of instance, however, you're wrong - calculating it on the fly for a join is **not** trivial - see Danielle's answer for some idea of how awkward it is to derive. In this type of instance, this sort of denormalisation is highly desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work -- just use GROUP BY and MIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Pr.SKU, Pr.Title, Pr.Weight_GM, MIN(PO.Postal_Charges) as PO_Charges
FROM Products Pr
   JOIN Postage Po ON Pr.Weight_GM <= Po.Weight_GM
GROUP BY Pr.SKU, Pr.Title, Pr.Weight_GM
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1702fa/6).

Comment: Nice, assuming that Postal Charges are smaller if weight is smaller, which seems logical in real world...

Comment: What about Products that weigh more than 50 GM?

Comment: Great question -- need the OP to answer that one!  Perhaps a max price regardless of the weight?  Who knows...

Comment: @rontornambe: There is no product in the product table which exceeds the upper limit of the weight in Postage Table.

Comment: Good to hear it -- then this should work.  Hope it helped.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
;With WeightNumber AS
(
   SELECT Weight_GM, Postal_Charge, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Weight_GM) AS Num 
   FROM Postage
)
WeightRange AS
(
   SELECT ISNULL(Prec.Weight_GM - 1, 0) AS START_WEIGHT, CurrentRow.Weight_GM AS END_WEIGHT, CurrentRow.Postal_Charge
   FROM WeightNumber CurrentRow
   LEFT JOIN WeightNumber Prec
      ON Prec.Num=CurrentRow.Num - 1
)
SELECT *
FROM Products p
JOIN WeightRange w 
   ON p.Weight_GM BETWEEN w.START_WEIGHT AND w.END_WEIGHT
```

Comment: This seems like it would get incorrect results for the starting weight since you are using between which would mean that a package that has a matching weight in the postage  table would get two results

Comment: @JoeW - It's worse than that, actually - they used `Prec.Weight_GM - 1`, which means that `START_WEIGHT` is actually **LESS** than `END_WEIGHT` for the previous row ([as shown in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73f3f/1) - after corrections to get it to run).  Showing the range isn't a bad idea, necessarily; however, the use of `BETWEEN` is likely to cause problems, and ranges should usually be thought of as having one end 'exclusive' (using `<` or `>`), especially for things like weight, time, and float values, which are 'infinitely' variable.

Comment: Well I wrote the query, but I didn't create tables and tested it. I think that the essential part of the query is there and that the query can be re-arranged easily to return the desired result

Comment: Even without the testing it the problems that where noted, using between and altering the starting weight which will cause invalid results to be returned should have been caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code 
The inner join will join the two tables with the key Weight_GM

```
select a.SKU, b.Postal Charges from Products a 
inner join Postage b on a.Weight_GM = b.Weight_GM
```

Comment: But as you see that the weight in the both tables are not the same. We should get the postage based on the Bands definde in the Postage Table. i.e if less than 20g take $1, if >20 and < 40 take $1.5 and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the OP's test data shows, weights for packages are rarely _exactly_ the cutoffs for charge ranges.  This won't work at all for his needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select SKU,Title,prds.Weight_GM b,pst.Weight_GM a,Postal_charges
from Postage pst ,Products prds 
where prds.Weight_GM < pst.Weight_GM
group by prds.Weight_GM;
```

here's the demo : [demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff27/8/0)

Comment: Your fiddle uses MySQL while the OP uses SQLServer - only MySQL allows you to include ungrouped, unaggregated fields in the select clause of a grouped query.